# Python lab zylab 18.3 Fun with Characters

Tags: python

Complete the check_character() function which has 2 parameters: A string, and a specified index. The function checks the character at the specified index of the string parameter, and returns a string based on the type of character at that location indicating if the character is a letter, digit, whitespace, or unknown character.

Ex: The function calls below with the given arguments will return the following strings:

```
check_character('happy birthday', 2) returns "Character 'p' is a letter"
check_character('happy birthday', 5) returns "Character ' ' is a white space"
check_character('happy birthday 2 you', 15) returns "Character '2' is a digit"
check_character('happy birthday!', 14) returns "Character '!' is unknown"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_character(word, index):
    char = word[index]
    typee = ''
    if char.isalpha():
        typee = 'a letter'
    elif char == ' ':
        typee = 'a white space'
    elif char.isdigit():
        typee = 'a digit'
    else:
        typee = 'unknown'
    
    return f"Character '{char}' is {typee}"
```

This is how I did the function and it was correct.

Comment: The indentation isn't correct.